# How to add amount of each day and show in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have few transaction records

i have shown them in recycler view and in the end i find total

now , i want to group them by date (each day)

and show how much amount is entered each day

eg:

nov 1 -500

nov 1 - 1000

total of nov 1       1500

nov 2 -400

nov 2 -200

total of nov 2     600

Comment: You can try using a HashMap for this. Something like __HashMap<Date, List<Double>>__ will work for your scenario.

Comment: Can you show your efforts to achieve this scenario ?